# Why inserting text three times produce a different result in Vim than using a count of 3 and inserting text once?

Tags: vim

#### Experiment 1

Launch vim and type these key sequences:

<kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>

You'll see the following text in the buffer.

```
abababccc
```

This happens because, after you insert the first `abc`, the cursor is on `c`, and when you press `i` again, it inserts the second `abc` *before* this `c`, and so on. Quoting `:help i` below.

```
<insert>    or              *i* *insert* *<Insert>*
i           Insert text before the cursor [count] times.
            When using CTRL-O in Insert mode |i_CTRL-O| the count
            is not supported.
```

#### Experiment 2

Launch vim and type these key sequences:

<kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>

You'll now see this in the buffer.

```
abcabcabc
```

Why does the result of experiment 2 not match that result of experiment 1 when experiment 2 is trying to do the same thing with a count prefix before the `i` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
iabc<Esc>iabc<Esc>iabc<Esc>
```

means "insert `abc`, then leave insert mode, then insert `abc`, then leave insert mode, then insert `abc`, then leave insert mode".

```
3iabc
```

means "insert abc three times"

The first one leaves insert mode between each insertion so the cursor lands on the character to the left and the next `i` inserts `abc` before the `c` of the previous insertion.

The second one never leaves insert mode so the `abc`'s are inserted one after the other.

Different commands leading to different results.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is due to cursor movements. As the help states, <kbd>i</kbd> inserts before the cursor. The cursor is "between b and c" or "on the c" after you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> for the first time.

If you do <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>, the sequence `abc` gets inserted three times before the current cursor.

I think you can also view this as <kbd>3</kbd>(<kbd>i</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>)<kbd>Esc</kbd>, so you have three times <kbd>Esc</kbd> in the first experiment vs. only one in the second.

Comment: As far as I understand, the count does not repeat the inserted text. The count repeats a command. In this case, it repeats the `i` command. So `3 i a b c` should repeat the `i` command three times and provide a result that is identical to that of experiment 1.